# Automatically increment version when publishing python package to pypi

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging

In order to get the version right when I upload a new distribution to PyPi, I have `setup.py` ask PyPi what the current version is (see function below), increment it, and use it as the `version` argument of the `setuptools.setup` call.

Sure enough, pip installing works, but installing from source doesn't (and anyway, we wouldn't want the installation to have the incorrect version number).

I could write a deploy script that would do the increment and call `setup` with the version number (and have `setup.py` use the current version instead).

But I'm guessing there's a best-practice tool to do what I'm trying to do already?

```py
def current_pypi_version(package: str) -> str:
    req = urllib.request.Request(f'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{package}/json')
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    if r.code == 200:
        t = json.loads(r.read())
        releases = t.get('releases', [])
        if releases:
            return sorted(releases)[-1]
```

Comment: @phd: Perhaps my title is misleading. I can fetch the current version number (my `current_pypi_version` function) and easily bumit up. My question is about where to put such logic since setup.py can be used both for packaging (where I'm fine) and for installation (in which case, I shouldn't be using the incremented version).

Answer (score 2):

There's a few third-party tools that do what you're looking for. For example, you could try http://pypi.org/p/bump (disclaimer, I am the author/maintainer), or you could try using https://pypi.org/p/setuptools-scm/ to generate versions from SCM metadata.